# Owin Bearer Token Authentication + Authorize controller

Tags: c#, authentication, token, owin

I'm trying to do authentication with Bearer tokens and owin.

I can issue the token fine using the grant type `password` and overriding `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` in **AuthorizationServerProvider.cs**.

But I can't reach a controller method with the `Authorize` attribute.

Here's my code:

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    // normal
    public Startup() : this(false) { }

    // testing
    public Startup(bool isDev)
    {
        // add settings
        Settings.Configure(isDev);

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider()
        };
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<LoanManager>(BaseManager.Create);

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

        // token generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Bearer",
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
        });
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationServerProvider.cs**

```
public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // enable CORS for all hosts, headers and methods
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "optional params",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // stop cookie auth
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        // add token bearer auth
        config.Filters.Add(new MyAuthenticationFilter());
        //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType));

        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute());

        if (Settings.IsDev == false)
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        }

        // make properties on model camelCased
        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
```

**MyAuthenticationFilter.cs** Custom filter used for debugging purposes

```
public class MyAuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (context.Principal != null && context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If I debug `AuthenticateAsync` in **MyAuthenticationFilter.cs** I see the header in the request:

```
Authorization: Bearer AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE_Cl...
```

But the Identity Claims are empty and `context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false.

Any ideas?

Comment: Microsoft has made a mistake, when releasing such an ugly complexity... I have stacked trying to find solution of the same problem for about 2 days...

Comment: I have stacked trying to find solution too. If you solve this, please, let me know.

Comment: That makes three of us.  This OWIN implementation is worse than the first version of WCF.  My Gosh - how hard can they make this??

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for the same solution, I spent a week or so on this and I left it. Today I started to search again, I found your questions and I was hoping to find an answer.

So I spent the whole day doing nothing other than trying all the possible solutions, merging suggestions with each other, I found some solution but they were long workarounds, to make the long story short here is what I found.

First of all if you need to authenticate the Web site with a custom third party identity provider token you need to have them both using the same machineKey or you need to have them both on the same server.

You need to add the **machineKey** to the `system.web` section as following:

**Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <machineKey validationKey="*****" decryptionKey="***" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

Here is a link to [generate a new machineKey](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machinekey) :

Now you need to move to the Startup.Auth.cs file where you can find the Startup.cs partial class, you need to define the OAuthBearerOptions

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }
    ...

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per    request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
        ...
    }
}
```

Replace your Login action inside AccountController with the following:

**AccountController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    /*This will depend totally on how you will get access to the identity provider and get your token, this is just a sample of how it would be done*/
    /*Get Access Token Start*/
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://youridentityproviderbaseurl");
    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName", model.Email));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", model.Password));
    HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);


    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("yourloginapi", content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string AccessToken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    /*Get Access Token End*/

    If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccessToken))
    {
            var ticket = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(AccessToken);
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(ticket.Identity.Claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, id);

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

   }

   ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Invalid Authentication");
   return View();
}
```

The last thing you need to do is to place this line of code  in the Global.asax.cs to avoid Anti Forgery exceptions:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

        …
    }
}
```

Hope this would work for you.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to me code work fine.
Thank you so much.
I will put up a write up to explain how it works when I am less busy.

Answer (score 4):

A year since this was posted, and I too experienced the same problem.

[image]

As you can see, my bearer token is recognized in the request headers, but my identity is still not be authenticated.

To fix, the short answer is make sure to configure your OAuth middleware *before* you configure your WebApi middleware (HttpConfiguration).

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I had to dig through source code and it's a lengthy explanation. If anyone cares for it i'll edit my post here. But the short answer is, just configure your oauth middleware before you configure your webapi middleware (HttpConfiguration).

Comment: @adOran I would appreciate a little more information on this, I can see that my middleware is starting up after my WebApi configuration. What was your approach to altering this order?

Comment: @TheSenator In your owin startup all you need to do is define your authorization provider before the web api. So basically, ((IAppBuilder)app).UseOauthAuthorizationServer; ((IAppBuilder)app).UseWebApi(). The reason why the order matters here is because the AuthorizationAttribute depends on the AuthenticationManager being defined beforehand.

Comment: I've abstracted my api's into classes so you end up with the class driving whether authentication is required. Is the [Authorize] attribute an absolute requirement? I've tried to move away from using that where possible!

Comment: I've just added the authorize attribute to the api itself, and now the framework is rejecting my Authorization header directly, so my jwt must be badly formed, put in the wrong place or mixed up with some other authentication mechanism. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here!

Comment: Solved my issue, I was missing this line: config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType));

Comment: This answer saved me (although had to dig in the comments for it - thus the edit). I was registering my OAuth middleware *after* app.UseWebApi(config) for some reason. Once I registered prior, `[Authorize]` worked as required.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have been working on this for some time now and I finally figured out what is wrong and now it is working.

It appears that your Cors enabling code on the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method is somehow overruling the header from the parameter. So by putting your first line right below your current third you will have your problem solved:

```
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

    IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

   context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

So far I haven't dug deeper to understand why this is so, but I believe that by adding the new header entry before getting the userManager somehow corrupts the data that is being sent by the post method on the client, in my case, an angular resource that goes like this:

```
    function userAccount($resource, appSettings) {
    return {
        registration: $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/Account/Register", null, 
                {
                    'registerUser' : { method : 'POST'}
                }
            ),
        login : $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/Token", null, 
                {
                    'loginUser': {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
                        },
                        transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                            var str = [];
                            for (var d in data) {
                                str.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
                            }
                            return str.join("&"); 
                        }
                    }
                } 
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but I had a problem with IsAuthenticated coming back false whilst using dependency injection (see SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983539/why-is-thread-currentprincipal-identity-isauthenticated-false-when-creating-an-i)) and it looked to because at the point of injection it hadn't been set by the Owin pipeline.

I overcame it by lazy injecting the Principal. Either way I put together a really basic application (which is linked to in the above)  to demonstrate the problem, but it might help you as it shows the Principal being set in the attribute and use of bearer authentication.