# Ninject Asp.Net WebApi Authorization Filter execution order

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have an authorization filter that checks a token. The filter is implemented as IAuthorizationFilter, with a reparate Atribute class, in order to enable constructor injection. This works fine. 
When the token is checked then it is stored in Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

The problem is when I use it in a controller that has that attribute. The controller also has a class injected, in which the current user must be known. It needs to use the right connection string for the database that belongs to the user group.

```
[TestAuthorizeToken]
public class TestController : BaseApiController
{
    IUserDetails user;

    public TestController(IUserDetails _user)
    {
        this.user = _user;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetClientCode")]
    public string GetClientCode()
    {
        return user.ClientCode;
    }
}
```

I assumed the filter code would always run first, so the identity is then checked and stored in the Thread.

But, to my surprise the UserDetails class is instantiated before the filter code runs. So I cannot use the identity in the UserDetails instantiation.

**Is there a way to make sure the Authorization code is the first thing that runs in this case?
Or am I overlooking something?**

The relevant bindings:

```
kernel.BindHttpFilter<TestAuthorizeTokenFilter>(System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterScope.Controller)
    .WhenControllerHas<TestAuthorizeTokenAttribute>();

kernel.Bind<IUserDetails>().To<UserDetails>();

kernel.Bind<IMasterUserRepoFactory>().ToFactory();
```

The filter:

```
public class TestAuthorizeTokenAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
}

public class TestAuthorizeTokenFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private IMasterUserRepo masterUserRepo;
    private IMasterUserRepoFactory masterUserRepoFactory;

    public TestAuthorizeTokenFilter(IMasterUserRepoFactory masterUserRepoFactory)
    {
        this.masterUserRepoFactory = masterUserRepoFactory;
    }

    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return continuation();  
        }

        masterUserRepo = this.masterUserRepoFactory.Create();

        AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;

        if (authHeader != null)
        {
            // Simplified
            string token = authHeader.Parameter;
            var masterUser = masterUserRepo.GetItemByToken(token);
            // ...
            var identity = new GenericIdentity(token);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

            return continuation();  
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
    }
}

public interface IMasterUserRepoFactory
{
    IMasterUserRepo Create();
}
```

Comment: maybe you are not performing authentication at the right place. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/25071817/1236044

Comment: @jbl thanks. Could you explain a little more? Am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: you may inject a factory of IUserDetails into your controller. So that the UserDetails gets resolved only in your actions. As to authentication, you may rely on a dedicated filter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/september/asp-net-asp-net-web-api-security-filters or use the authentication process provided by owin

Comment: @jbl that is it. I will look into using factories in the controllers, or use <Lazy> perhaps. Thank you!